# Arrow UIPopoverController on UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios4, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol, uiactionsheet

I have a segmentedcontrol on the rightbarbuttonitem with 4 buttons. Rightnow this code works:

```
[actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:self.switchView.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem animated:YES];
```

But the arrow of the UIActionSheet (popover) doesn't point right. So i probably have to use this:

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated];
```

But i don't know how to use it properly.. I tried different approaches but with no good results. Someone having this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like.

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:self.switchview.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```